# Building linear m values

Tags: linear-referencing

I had to manually build M values for hundreds of levees (in the downstream direction) and wondering if there is a way to check that I didn't miss any levees. Is there a way I can look-up a table with all the "M" values other than clicking on on each individual levee?

Ideally I would like to be able to use Field Calculator to populate a new column with every segment's M value so I could see if there are any 0 values.

Comment: Is a levee represented as a polyline?  If so, does each point in the polyline have the same M value?  By "segment", do you mean individual segments within a single polyline?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I found was to go to the **"Routes" tab under layer properties**. From there you are able to symbolize lines with no M value or "NaN" in a different manner under "Route Measure Anomalies". These lines then contrast compared to the rest.

Answer (score 2):

If your table of levees had a from value and to value field, the create routes tool would have added the m-values based on the length of the line.  Also, if the table has a from value and to value field you could map the table back to the feature class.  If one levee does not have any m-values that row will not be placed in the output.  There is probably a better answer, however.